# java delay method crashes system

Tags: java, applet, awt, lag, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to make a program that models two characters that are racing along a track in a java applet using netbeans. I currently have the racing logic and graphics working fine, but I'm having trouble implementing a delay to show each move the characters make individually.

To create a delay, I currently have this method written:

```
public void delay()
{

try
            {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            }

catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

However, this causes the program to lag so much that it crashes the appletViewer. How can I delay the system such that it doesn't lag the system?

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Are the components based on AWT or Swing?  Either way, don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which thread do you call delay()?
The UI thread? If it is the case, you may your applet not responsive and break your app. Try the callback function approach.